# How is the connection 1 form defined?

Tags: lie-algebras, connections, principal-bundles

I am studying connection on principal bundles and the definition I've encountered is the following
"A connection over a principal G-bundle p:P$\rightarrow$B is a splitting of the Altiah sequence
$$\tilde{ω}.TP\rightarrow VP ≃ P\times\mathfrak{g}$$
$$u\mapsto (\pi_{P}(u),ω|_{\pi_{p}(u)}(u))$$
where $ω$ is a 1-form over P with values in $\mathfrak{g}$, $ω\in \mathcal{A}^{1}(P)\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ that is G-equivariant".
Now, I can't understand how the latter bundle is defined. Cause we know how to build a tensor product of two vector bundles, but here $\mathfrak{g}$ is just $T_{e}G$ (a vector space), so which bundle should I consider?

Comment: @nicrot000 I disagree - the bundle $VP$, the vertical subbundle of the tangent bundle $TP\to P$, is locally isomorphic to $P\times \mathfrak g$. It is a vector bundle over $P$.

Comment: Yeah sure, stupid of me. But isn't it already globally isomorphic to $P\times\mathfrak{g}$? If you pick a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$, then the respective fundamental vector fields are a frame for $VP$.

Comment: However, then the question is answered by that $\mathcal{A}^1(P)\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ is not the tensor product of two bundles, but of the vector spaces $\mathcal{A}^1(P)$ (which is a somewhat unusual notation for, I suspect, 1-forms on the manifold) and $\mathfrak{g}$.